# Exclude everything but Javascript files in RequireJS Optimizer

Tags: javascript, regex, requirejs, requirejs-optimizer

I am using RequireJS optimizer in a gulp recipe to compile and concatenate my Modules but redundant 3rd party library files like bower.json and *.nuspec files are being copied to my output directory.

I have successfully managed to exclude full directories using fileExclusionRegExp in the requirejs.optimize options object with the following expression:

`/^\.|^styles$|^templates$|^tests$|^webdriver$/`

However, I cannot figure out how to exclude everything but `.js` file extensions. I could use the following:

`/^\.|.json$|.nuspec$|^styles$|^templates$|^tests$|^webdriver$/`

to exclude specific extensions but if a new type were to appear later, I would have to notice and then change the regex. Also, the regex would probably become unruly and hard to maintain with time. I have tried to use the following expressions:

`/^\.|!js$|^styles$|^templates$|^tests$|^webdriver$/`

`/^\.|!.js$|^styles$|^templates$|^tests$|^webdriver$/`

`/^\.|^.js$|^styles$|^templates$|^tests$|^webdriver$/`

`/^\.|[^.js$]|^styles$|^templates$|^tests$|^webdriver$/`

`/^\.|[^.js]$|^styles$|^templates$|^tests$|^webdriver$/`

The results ranged from doing nothing (the first 3, to breaking the build, last 2) any help anyone could provide would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: just add  a negative lookahead at the start `^(?!.*\.js$)`

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work. It appears, although I am not 100% sure, that your answer is preventing the copy of my source `.js` files and then the build breaks because of missing files the same as my last 2 attempts.

If I log the files RequireJS is compiling using the onBuildRead function it seems to suggest that only the primary module name `.js` files are in the build directory, which I think is the directory in which the minification is performed

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
^\.|\.(json|nuspec)$|^(styles|templates|tests|webdriver)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: That is certainly cleaner and shorter than my implementation but it still means I would have to append new file formats if including another 3rd-party library later with different extensions later. Thanks for the suggestion though